# Does the "/Volumes" name changes based on system language, if yes how to adapt this?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xamarin

I am using this code to check if the client runs from DMG /Volume, and show an alert and quit.

```
private void IsRunningFromDMG()
{
        var currentPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;

        if (currentPath.StartsWith("/Volumes", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            using (var alert = new NSAlert
            {
                MessageText = "Warning",
                InformativeText = "You cannot run this application from DMG, drag move to the " +
                    "\"/Applications\" folder"
            })

            {
                alert.RunModal();
                NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(null);
            }
        }
}
```

This is fine if the system language is set to English. I doubt if the /Volumes reacts to localization in that case how to do it?

There should be a system defined constant that would take care of it?
If it is, please help me to know what is it.

Comment: Suggestion: It would probably be sufficient to simply get the volume information for the running application and see if the app is running from a read-only volume. Technically, a DMG can be mounted at any path, and in future versions of Gate Keeper they might be.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem paths do not change based on localization, they are localized for "display" though (i.e. Pictures, Music, etc... would be localized in Finder for display to the user but the filesystem path is still `/User/xxx/Pictures`, etc...)

> Localized names. The system provides localized names for many system directories, such as Applications, Library, Music, Movies. An app may similarly provide localized names for itself and for any directories it creates.
>
> **Display names do not affect the actual name of the file in the file system**. Code that accesses a file or directory programmatically must specify the item’s actual name when opening or manipulating the item using the file system interfaces. The only time your app should ever use display names is when displaying the name of a file or directory to the user. You can get the display name for any file or directory using the displayNameAtPath: method of NSFileManager.

i.e.

```
var urls = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationsDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.System);
var applicationDisplayName = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.DisplayName(urls[0].AbsoluteString);
```

Note: You should use `NSSearchPathDirectory.AllApplicationsDirectory` within the `NSSearchPathDomain.All` domain to obtain a valid list of "Application" urls where your application might/should be located at, instead of hard coding it to the "System" application location.

Comment: Yep, for others I use NSSearchPath. but how to use for /Volumes ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya There is no "display" localization for "Volumes"

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. Thanks a lot.